# Group by in R with like on multiple constraints

Tags: r, data.table

currently I try to learn R but I stuck with the following.
I had this table

```
                       material       V1
1:                       Silber 450.7886
2:                Kupfer-Nickel   0.0000
3:                Silver Tantal  26.9928
4: Bimetall (Silber - Niobium))   8.9925
```

now I want to sum all rows that contains one string of a list of possibilities.
My current approach is

```
merge <- c("Silver", "Silber")
materialsSplitted[any(sapply(merge, function(x) grepl(x, material, TRUE)))]
```

but the problem is I get the same table as the input is.

Comment: Please asssign the output back to a new object or the initial object

Comment: it creates the same table

Comment: I think it is `any` causes issue, Try `Reduce("|", lapply(merge, `

Comment: You could also pre-combine merge into a single pattern, `patt <- paste(merge, collapse="|"); DT[material %like% patt]`

Comment: @Frank thanks for this idea, I'm a beginner and will look into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in using `any` wrapped with `sapply`.  `sapply` returns a logical `matrix`

```
materialsSplitted[,sapply(merge, function(x) grepl(x, material, TRUE))]
#     Silver Silber
#[1,]  FALSE   TRUE
#[2,]  FALSE  FALSE
#[3,]   TRUE  FALSE
#[4,]  FALSE   TRUE
```

and when we wrap with `any`, according to `?any`

> The value is a logical vector of length one.

So, here, it have TRUE/FALSE values and return a single `TRUE`

```
materialsSplitted[, any(sapply(merge, function(x) grepl(x, material, TRUE)))]
#[1] TRUE
```

which gets recycled as row index to return all the rows.  Instead, we need to check for each row, whether there is a string match.  For this, we can use `Reduce`

```
materialsSplitted[Reduce(`|`, lapply(merge, function(x) grepl(x, material, TRUE)))]
#                       material       V1
#1:                       Silber 450.7886
#2:                Silver Tantal  26.9928
#3: Bimetall (Silber - Niobium))   8.9925
```

Comment: Maybe it's a silly question, but wouldn't it also work with rowSums or colSums? When applied to a logical array, it's more or less equivalent to a logical or (check if the result is >0 to have the answer as a boolean).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  Yes, you can create a logical vector from the `sapply` output with `rowSums` as well, `rowSums(sapply(...)) > 0`